# How can I insert a bash variable into an SQLite SQL statement as part of a script?

Tags: sql, linux, bash, sqlite, shell

**Context**

I am using a code quality analysis tool ('scc') which loops through my Gitlab repositories and analyses the code found within them. The tool initially creates an SQLite table, then outputs a row of data to this SQLite table during each loop.

I am attempting to add an additional column after each row of data is written to the SQLite table during each loop iteration. I want to add the contents of a variable which changes with each loop iteration as the entry to the additional column.

*Example:*

Loop iteration 1:

$repository = project1

Code quality analysis output table:

| Project | File | nCode | nComment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yellow | yellow.py | 5 | 1 |

After adding additional column and entry to row:

| Project | File | nCode | nComment | httpUrlToRepo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yellow | yellow.py | 5 | 1 | project1 |

Loop iteration 2:

$repository = project2

After code quality analysis tool output and adding entry to additional column:

| Project | File | nCode | nComment | httpUrlToRepo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yellow | yellow.py | 5 | 1 | project1 |
| Green | green.py | 6 | 4 | project2 |

**Code**

Note: `repositories` contains an array of repository names found by scanning my Gitlab account.

```
counter=1

for repository in "${repositories[@]}"; do
    echo "Running scc analysis on ${repofolder}."
    
    echo "counter: ${counter}"

        if [ "${counter}" -eq "1" ]; 
        then
          echo "Creating table and adding data to analysis.db"
          scc -f sql --sql-project ${repofolder} ./${repofolder} | sqlite3 analysis.db
          sqlite3 analysis.db 'ALTER TABLE t ADD httpUrlToRepo TEXT;'
          sqlite3 analysis.db 'UPDATE t SET httpUrlToRepo="$repository" WHERE httpUrlToRepo IS NULL;'
        else
          echo "Inserting data to analysis.db"
          scc -f sql-insert --sql-project ${repofolder} ./${repofolder} | sqlite3 analysis.db
          sqlite3 analysis.db 'UPDATE t SET httpUrlToRepo="$repository" WHERE httpUrlToRepo IS NULL;'
          fi
        fi

        rm -r $repofolder

        counter=$((counter+1))

    continue
done
```

The logic is as follows:

1. On the first loop iteration, where counter=1, scc will create a new table and output code quality analysis data as an SQLite row to this table.
2. Update the table schema to add a new row 'httpUrlToRepo'.
3. Where column 'httpUrlToRepo' is empty, add the content of the variable $repository to the column. This should be just the entry to the single row in the table.
4. On subsequent loop iterations, where counter!=1, scc will add a new row to the table containing the code quality analysis data.
5. The column 'httpUrlToRepo' will be updated where it is empty (in my mind, the only entry to be empty in this column is the current row as previous iterations should have inserted data). The content of variable $repository will be added to this row.

**Actual Results**

The problem with my approach so far lies in using the $repository variable in the SQL statement here `sqlite3 analysis.db 'UPDATE t SET httpUrlToRepo="$repository" WHERE httpUrlToRepo IS NULL;`

Depending on how I try to implement the variable insertion into the SQL statement, either the string "${repository}" is added to all entries in the column, or I get a parse error.

So far, I have tried to insert the variable as: `${repository}`, `$repository`, `"${repository}"`, `&repository`, and `""${repository}""`.

**Question**

My question is two-fold:

- Is the approach of adding a new column and inserting the contents of a variable the best method?
- If so, how can I properly inject a bash variable into the SQL statement?

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is that in *bash* the **single quotes** does not expand shell variable so, for example, you have to replace:

```
'UPDATE t SET httpUrlToRepo="$repository" WHERE httpUrlToRepo IS NULL;'
```

with

```
"UPDATE t SET httpUrlToRepo=\"$repository\" WHERE httpUrlToRepo IS NULL;"
```

Then repeat it for all your statements...

Answer (score -1):

I have found an answer to the second question I had: 'how can I properly inject a bash variable into the SQL statement?'.

In my case, I needed to use

`sqlite3 analysis.db "UPDATE t SET httpUrlToRepo='"$repository"' WHERE httpUrlToRepo IS NULL;"`

This would evaluate to the following, where `$repository=project1`:

`sqlite3 analysis.db "UPDATE t SET httpUrlToRepo='project1' WHERE httpUrlToRepo IS NULL;"`

The statement lies within double-quotes. Single-quotes are used to begin and end the string, where double-quotes end and re-open the SQL statement and contain the variable reference.